# Python application not recognizing updates made in python file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written python code in file.py which is in the directory containing python application.
Python version is Python 2.7.4. Platform is Windows 7.

I imported file.py to python application and made changes to file.py while keeping the python application window on. But changes are not reflected. Every time changes are made in file.py, I will have to close python application and import file.py again for the changes to be reflected.

Is there away to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `reload(file)` in your application code every time after you changing something. It will reflect the change to your application code.